# GDB Debugger how to code sign and set path variables

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb

I have gdb installed on my 2015 mac Yosemite 10.10.5. To run gdb I have to type ggdb. How do I make it so I can type gdb and it will run ggdb.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias command is your friend. How you define an alias depends on which shell you are using. For zsh for instance you can use the following

```
alias gdb=ggdb
```